# Why can a one-element set (a singleton) be a member of another set but not a subset of it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have came across this in a textbook:

> $\{2\}\nsubseteq\{\{2\}\}$ but $\{2\}\in\{\{2\}\}$

I understand that $\{2\}$ is an element (member) of the other set but considering $\{2\}$ is a set itself, why is it not a subset?

Comment: I think that I wrote an answer to this about 30 times now. I'll go fetch a duplicate. Hang on.

Comment: The subsets of $A=\{\{2\}\}$ are elements in $\mathcal{P}(\{\{2\}\})=\{\emptyset,A\}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila sorry

Comment: @Listing I think I get it actually. Are you saying that as a subset is a set of the elements in another set, as {2} is an element of the other set it cannot essentially exist as its own in this context, it must be contained within a set i.e. {{2}} thus making it equal and not a subset? (I'm not a mathematician, sorry about the informal logic)

Comment: Not word for word, but surely close enough to help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169198/element-of-a-set/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135218/set-theory-subset-of-set/ (And I am far more than certain there are a couple more!)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for taking the time to find those links and to edit my question.

Comment: Try to recall the definition of a subset. It helps you to understand why {2}⊈{{2}}.

Answer (score 6):

The assertion $\{ 2 \} \subseteq \{ \{ 2 \} \}$ states that every element of $\{2\}$ is an element of $\{\{2\}\}$. But $2$ is the only element of $\{2\}$, and $2$ is not an element of $\{\{2\}\}$ because the only element of this latter set is $\{2\}$, and $2 \ne \{2\}$!

Just because something is a set and it's an *element* of another set doesn't mean it's a *subset* of it.

Comment: Took me a lot of times to read through that to fully understand it. But I couldn't have asked for a better explanation. Thank you. I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

To phrase it differently:

1. $\{\{2\}\}$ is a set containing a set
2. $\{2\}$ is a set containing a number

Since they are sets containing different kind of things, they cannot have a superset-subset relation to each other...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: (Depends on the definitions, $\{2\}$ is also a set containing a set.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think I know what you mean, but that would make $\{\{2\}\}$ a set containing a set containing a set... Still I do not see why this would be necessary to think about in the current situation. It rather complicates things.

Comment: Is the set it contains, the empty set?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Comment: But it is really irrelevant as it confuses the point...

Comment: String: I used to think so myself. But I have to say that pointing out to students in the first class of the semester/year/degree, that sets can be (and usually are) members of other sets is important. The point is that at least in our common-sense interpretation of things, $2\neq\{2\}$, and therefore $\{2\}$ and $\{\{2\}\}$ are different sets with different elements.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ok, you are probably right. I just though that the current case was hard enough...