# Why {{x}} is a subset of S but not {x} if S={{ x }}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Starting my self-study of the book "A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics", I came up with the following stone in the road (on page 2 incidentally).

> We say T is a *subset* of a set S if every element of T also belongs
> to S... We write T ⊆ S if T is a subset of S, and T ⊄ S if not. For
> example, S={1, {2}, cat}
>
> {cat} ⊆ S, {{2}} ⊆ S, {2} ⊄ S

My question is why is `{2} ⊄ s`(or {{2}}⊆ S) ? Why does the inclusion property not propagate down the subsets? Is this just a stricter definition of inclusion? I still wonder how I haven't thought about this question after years of university studies.

Comment: The elements of $\{ 2 \}$ include $2$ and $2$ is not an element of $S$. There is no "propagating down the subsets", each set is its own object.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/empty-set-does-not-belong-to-empty-set)

Comment: There is a key difference between the relation "to be an element of" ($\in$) and the relation "to be a subset of" ($\subseteq$). The second one is defined in terms of the first one: "a is a *subset* of b iff (for every x, if x is in a, then x is in b).

Comment: And see also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638560/why-can-a-1-element-set-be-a-member-of-another-set-but-not-a-subset-of-it)

Comment: If you apply the def of *subset*, you can easily check that it **does not** hold, because set $\{ 2 \}$ has the number $2$ as *element* and $2$ is not an element of $S$ ($2$ it is not listed in the explicit def of $S$). You must be aware of the fact (see linked posts) that the object $2$ and the set $\{ 2 \}$ having the object $2$ as single element are **not** the same.

Comment: I see!! So I mixed the definitions of ∈ and ⊆ . Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of the set $\{1,\{2\}, \mathrm{cat}\}$ are $1$, $\{2\}$ and $\mathrm{cat}$.

So in relation to the set $S$, we have that $\{2\}$ is an element of this set (which is a set containing 2). But it is not a subset of $S$.

This would be $\{\{2\}\}$. A set containing this element.

When we have $A\subseteq B$ that means that every element $a\in A$ has to be an element of $B$. But $\{2\}\subseteq S$ would mean that $2\in S$. Which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Any set is a subset of itself. And $\{x\}$ is just an element of $\{\{x\}\}$.